# Firebase Android NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH not working while app is in background

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented firebase successfully. The only thing I am not able to achieve is NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH. Its working when the app is in foreground. In my PHP code I have added priority and its value to high. Though it seems to be useless for android. In my ios app priority high is working. I am not able to figure out how this can be done. Just for your Info : I am aware of payload data and notifications. :) Thank you.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //Displaying data in log
    //It is optional
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Title: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    String imageUrl = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
    bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUrl);
    //Calling method to generate notification
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
}


private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String title) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Log.e("inside notification", "method");
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_bicycle)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimary))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody));
         notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(img))
    }
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Random rn = new Random();
    int result = rn.nextInt(100 + 1);
    notificationManager.notify(result, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by aware of payload DATA and NOTIFICATION ? Please can you share your json that you are sending to firebase endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer from [another similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777977/firebasemessagingservice-intent-putextra-does-not-work-if-app-is-not-running/39795691#39795691). The **issue is within onMessageReceived()** method **not just priority**.

From your question I can see that **you are sending Notification payload as well** from server which is the **root cause** of this problem.

---

**onMessageReceived()** method **will not be called** if the app is in **background or killed** and if the message sent **contains DATA and NOTIFICATION payload both.**

**When app is not running** you will anyway receive notification. But if you want to intercept data via onMessageReceived() then you will have to create a custom app server which will **send only DATA payload** to fcm endpoint.

something like this:

```
 {
   "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
   "data" : {
     "Title" : "Title for Notification",
     "body" : "Notification body can go here",
     "Room" : "Something extra"
   },
 }
```

Hope this solves your issue. (You can refer to [fcm documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) which says)

> When your app is in **the background**, Android directs notification
>   messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the
>   app launcher **by default**.
>
> This includes messages that contain both notification and data payload
>   (and all messages sent from the Notifications console). In these
>   cases, the notification is delivered to the device's system tray, and
>   the **data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your
>   launcher Activity.**

*So, onMessageReceived() is never called! If you want to handle stuff manually in onMessageReceived follow the instructions in this answer.*